# Advance cell reference on Excel refresh

Tags: excel, vba

i wonder if you can help me.

I have an excel document with two sheets, 'data' and 'output'. I'm using cell reference `=data!A1`. But i'd like it to advance by ten rows, e.g. `=data!A11` every time excel refreshes (by refresh i mean, every time it runs a formula for example `=rand`.

The reason behind it needing to run like this is the cell will need to advance ten spaces for each page printed.

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Edit: Sorry if it i wasn't clear at first, i need a macro or formula to advance the 'cell reference' by ten rows, on excel refresh. Example above.

Comment: what is your question.......?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, i need a macro (or formula) to increase the cell the reference by ten (e.g. `=data!A1` to `=data!A11`) on excel refresh.

Comment: Have you tried to write a macro, or formula?

Comment: Yes! I've tried a number of things i've found on the web. Here is a formula i tried but it only seems to add to the value once, not incrementally.. `=INDEX(A:A,ROW()*3-2)`

Comment: easiest google ever... http://support.microsoft.com/KB/152265

Comment: Good find, however this formula operates much the same as my previous link. It does not add one to the value on the document refresh. It only seems to work once.

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by `refresh`, and what your ultimate requirement is.  You mentioned printing -- can you elaborate on what exactly you need?

Comment: Indeed, so when you use a formula for example `=rand ` to generate a random number. The number will change every time you do something within excel (which i'm defining as an 'excel refresh'). This number will also change each time you print. My end goal is to have the cell reference increasing by ten rows each time the page prints.

Comment: So your goal is to do the increment every time there is a print action, yes?  Is it important that it performs the action for every **page**, or would it be sufficient to do it once per print action?

Comment: Every page is essential. As i'm using it to display cells inside another sheet, 'output' print, then move on to the next increment of cells print etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various Events that you can capture, but I don't think any of them will meet your exact need.

You can add this to the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

code in this sub will be run any time something in the workbook changes.  But based on your explanation of your requirement, I don't think it's appropriate, for two reasons:

- It will fire any time **any** cell value changes, which may not be what you want
- You indicated that you're trying to capture Print actions, but in my test (Excel 2010), this was not fired when I printed the workbook (I also did not see a change in a cell with `=Rand()`

You can use this code in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

As its name implies, it will be run before any print action.  This is fired once per **workbook**; there is no equivalent at the worksheet level (though it would be pretty easy to simply iterate through each worksheet).  Also, it occurs **before** the print takes place; I assume you want the formula incremented afterwards.

I believe the best option for you is to create a macro that performs the entire operation:

1. Print: call `ThisWorkbook.PrintOut`, or iterate through each sheet and call `sheet.PrintOut`
2. Increment a single cell on each worksheet
3. Use an `OFFSET` function (see BigRabbit's answer) to reference the incremented cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula here.

`=OFFSET(<Starting_Cell>,(ROW()-<Current_Row>)*<Inc>,0)`

More specifically this right here should work.

`=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)*10,0)`